# Unable to Connect to RDS Instance with IAM Auth via mysql CLI Tool

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

This is what I've accomplished so far:

1) I created an AWS IAM user that belongs to the AdministratorAccess group. In addition, I created and attached a policy to this user so as to allow access to the RDS instance. The policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:<region>:<account id>:<user>:<DB instance resource id>/<DB instance user>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is derived from an example in AWS's documentation: [Creating and Using an IAM Policy for IAM Database Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html)

However, after creating the policy, I am given the following errors:

[image]

I've looked around, but can't figure out how to resolve these errors.

2) I created an RDS instance with IAM DB Authentication Enabled. Following this, I added a rule to the instance's Security Group which allows my laptop to connect to the DB instance.

3) Lastly, following the directions in "[Command Line: AWS CLI and mysql Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html)", I created a script for connecting to the database from my laptop. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="<IAM user>"

CERTIFICATE="<full path>/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"

RDSHOST="<RDS instance Endpoint>"

TOKEN="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 3306 --region us-west-2 --username $USERNAME)"

mysql --host=$RDSHOST --port=3306 --ssl-ca=$CERTIFICATE --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=$USERNAME --password=$TOKEN
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<IAM user>'@'c-73-227-21-39.hsd1.ct.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
```

It appears the issue may be due to the errors in the policy I created, but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate some advice/help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a DB user. [Creating a Database Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.DBAccounts.html) and the username should be the DB user, not the IAM user

```
CREATE USER jane_doe IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin AS 'RDS';
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the issue. To your answer, I would also include a couple of additional links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html (Connecting to an Amazon RDS DB Instance) and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html (Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine). In case someone is not aware, in order to run the script above you must first connect to the database using the RDS instance's master user and password. The links above show you how.